# Object.assign(object1[i]) in javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Let say, object1 has 10 objects.
And this code assigns object1 to object2

```
const object2 = Object.assign(object1);
```

But I want to assign 5 objects only from object1 using for loop.

```
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    object2 = Object.assign(object1[i]);
}
// but this one won't work.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `Object.assign(x)` just returns `x`. Why are you using Object.assign at all? It is useless when used with only one argument.

Comment: `object2 = Object.assign({}, ...object1);`

Comment: You don't iterate objects with a `for` loop... passing one argument to `Object.assign` is useless... what are you actually trying to do here? Give a real example.

Comment: @Paulpro, because Object1 has many properties and I don't want to list all properties, if it's posible

Comment: @noyruto88 If you're trying to make a shallow copy with Object.assign, you need two arguments. Like this: `object2 = Object.assign({},object1);`

Comment: @Paulpro, can i do that inside loop? I have a reason why i need this to be inside loop.

Comment: What is the reason? Are you trying to copy the first five properties of the object? Object's are not ordered so there is no such thing as "the first five".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I am assuming both obj1 and obj2 are arrays

```js
var obj1 = []
    for (let i=0; i< 10; i++)
    {
        obj1.push({key: i});
    }
    var obj2 = []
    for (let i=0; i< 5; i++)
    {
        obj2.push(obj1[i]);
    }
```

2. I am assuming you're learning `Object.assign()`. It is used to clone or modify original object to target object

```js
    var obj1 = {key:1, foo: 'bar'};
    var obj2 = Object.assign({}, obj1);    //clone all properties
    var obj3 = Object.assign({foo: 'not bar', newprop: 'anything'}, obj1);    //copy the original, modify `foo` property and add `newprop`
    //you can iterate through properties with this
    for (var property in obj3) {
    if (obj3.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
          // do stuff, may be filter which property you want to get, etc
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks bro. this one obj2.push(obj1[i]); is the answer to my problem.